# Is there a way to loop inside an object to print the values of all its members in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

recently I was in an interview, and the last question in the interview was to make a function that takes an object as an argument. The function has to loop inside the passed object to print all of the values of its attributes.
something like`for/in` in javascript
is there such thing in c++ ?

Comment: Unless you know the object type and all of its public members, there's no way in C++. It just doesn't support introspection. Either you misunderstood the question, or it was a trick question to make you sweat.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and I have to access each attribute separately same as ```obj.attName```, or there is a way to access the object's attributes anonymously?

Comment: It is possible to build something on top of C++ compiler that does it. For example llvm provides a way to do it quite easily. But that would be done not using C++ itself.

Comment: "and I have to access each attribute separately same as obj.attName" there is not reflection in C++ (at least not yet)

Comment: @Slava , thx a lot. so it was like a tricky question from the interviewer and he was not expecting any answers.

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa the interviewer definitely did **not** expect no answer. He or she expected an answer to show your level of knowledge of the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do this for some kinds of types.

For tuple-like types (see [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)):

```
template<typename T> void print(T&& tuple) {
    apply([](auto&&... elements) { (..., (std::cout << elements << '\n')); }, tuple);
}

int main() { print(std::tuple{1, 2.3, "abc"}); }
```

For aggregate types if you know the number of their fields (see [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)):

```
template<typename T> void print(T&& two_fields_aggregate) {
    auto&& [a, b] = two_fields_aggregate;
    std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n';
}

struct Example {
    int i;
    double d;
};

int main() { print(Example{1, 2.3}); }
```

The hardest case: aggregate types if you don't know the number of their fields (see [Boost.MagicGet](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)):

```
template<typename T> void print(T&& aggregate) {
    apply(
        [](auto&&... elements) { (..., (std::cout << elements << '\n')); },
        boost::pfr::structure_to_tuple(aggregate)
    );
}

struct Example {
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string_view s;
};

int main() { print(Example{1, 2.3, "abc"}); }
```

If your object has private data, you obviously cannot access it from the outside, therefore cannot print it.